# Images wont load in html page via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image gallery html page with a div that gets populated from a javascript file.

Here is the html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="US-ASCII">
<title>Gallery</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="example"></div>


<script src="js/gallery.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the gallery.js file

```
var images = [ "img/mccc/001.jpg", "img/mccc/002.jpg", "img/mccc/003.jpg",
    "img/mccc/004.jpg", "img/mccc/005.jpg", "img/mccc/006.jpg",
    "img/mccc/007.jpg", "img/mccc/008.jpg", "img/mccc/009.jpg",
    "img/mccc/010.jpg", "img/mccc/011.jpg", "img/mccc/012.jpg",
    "img/mccc/013.jpg", "img/mccc/014.jpg", "img/mccc/015.jpg",
    "img/mccc/016.jpg", "img/mccc/017.jpg", "img/mccc/018.jpg",
    "img/mccc/019.jpg", "img/mccc/020.jpg", "img/mccc/021.jpg",
    "img/mccc/022.jpg", "img/mccc/023.jpg", "img/mccc/024.jpg",
    "img/mccc/025.jpg" ];

var code = "";

for ( var i in images) {
    code += '<img src="' + i + '" alt="image not available">';
}

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = code;
```

the 'img' folder which contains the 'mccc' folder is in the same directory as my gallery.html and 'js' folder, and yes, the images named 001.jpg-025.jpg are in the 'mccc' folder.

This is what I get when I load the page

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: In the broken images, Use inspect element to get the actual `src` of the img, can you view that `src` from the browser?
I suspect that `src` isn't valid

Comment: `../img/mcc/xxx.jpg` since your js file isn't in your root directory.

Comment: To debug cases like this, use your browser's "developer tools" to inspect the generated source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
for ( var i in images) {
   code += '<img src="' + i + '" alt="image not available">';
}
```

To this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
   code += '<img src="' + images[i] + '" alt="image not available">';
}
```

The `for ( var foo in bar )` construct doesn't do what you think it does. It iterates the *properties* of the object, which in the case of the array are unordered array indices, not array values.

Note: Several answers suggest you keep the `for...in` syntax and index your array properly. This will probably work in the basic case, but it is not recommended for two reasons:

1. Iterting an array in this way is not guaranteed to go in index order. So if you want your images in the same order as they appear in the array, you could get burned.
2. The `for...in` syntax iterates all properties of the array, not just elements in the array. A base array like you have here, with no magic in play from third party libraries, etc..., does not have any additional properties. But it might, and then your code would break.

The **right** way to iterate an array is with a standard `for` loop. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) which says:

> for..in should not be used to iterate over an Array where index order is important. Array indexes are just enumerable properties with integer names and are otherwise identical to general Object properties. There is no guarantee that for...in will return the indexes in any particular order and it will return all enumerable properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are inherited.
>
> Because the order of iteration is implementation dependent, iterating over an array may not visit elements in a consistent order. Therefore it is better to use a for loop with a numeric index (or Array.forEach or the non-standard for...of loop) when iterating over arrays where the order of access is important.

Comment: Thank you for adding the additional information to your answer. This has been most helpful!

Answer (score 4):

When you use `for (var i in images)`, `i` becomes the *index*, not the element itself. Try:

```
for (var i in images) {
    code += '<img src="' + images[i] + '" alt="image not available">';
}
```

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. I was trying to do it the Java way. Thank you!

Comment: See the update to my answer below. This will work in the simple case, but it is not safe.

Answer (score 3):

Just Change:

```
for ( var i in images) {
    code += '<img src="' + i + '" alt="image not available">';
}
```

to

```
for ( var i in images) {
    code += '<img src="' + images[i] + '" alt="image not available">';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the developer tools that come with the browser to further investigate - sometimes the paths get messed up depending on the url of the file loading the javascript.  I would put the full URL to the pictures in the array - that way there isnt confusion.